# Using of Mat-sort-header

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular and Angular Material.

I'm trying to building tables with Angular Material and I've found this part "mat-sort-header", I want to know what **mat-sort-header** means in a complete description?

Comment: Refer - https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey BatAmbra, welcome to SO. First of all, have you read the [angular documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)?

Comment: Yes, I've read all the official documentation about Angular.